# Error 1004 - This selection is not valid on Range.Insert

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a runtime error 1004 - this selection is not valid error, when attempting to run a VBA amcro in excel.

I have looked around for solutions, and all the ones I have tried have so far been unsuccessful (activating worksheet, clearing rows below data to make sure there is room for insert and other I can't remember).

What I am trying to do:

We have a data set that needs to be sorted based on three columns, unfortunately the in-built sort doesn't work as we would like. The three columns are machine, shift and date/time. Example data (sorted by date/time):

```
Machine1  Days  02/05/2013 07:05
Machine2  Days  02/05/2013 07:05
Machine1  Days  02/05/2013 08:45
Machine1  Late  02/05/2013 15:05
```

We would like this to be sorted so it would appear like this:

```
Machine1  Days  02/05/2013 07:05
Machine1  Days  02/05/2013 08:45
Machine2  Days  02/05/2013 07:05
Machine1  Late  02/05/2013 15:05
```

**My Code:**

```
For rowCount = 4 To 5000
    On Error GoTo nextLoop
    Worksheets("Schedule").Activate
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(rowCount, 1).Value = "" Then
         Exit For
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(rowCount + 1, 1).Value = "" Then
         Exit For
    End If

    thisMachine = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowCount, 2).Value
    thisShift = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowCount, 4).Value
    thisDay = Mid(ActiveSheet.Cells(rowCount, 5).Value, 1, 10)

    pasteRow = rowCount + 1
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(rowCount + 2, 4).Value <> thisShift Then
        GoTo nextLoop
    End If

    For internalCount = rowCount + 1 To 5000
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(internalCount, 4).Value <> thisShift Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If Mid(ActiveSheet.Cells(internalCount, 5).Value, 1, 10) <> thisDay Then
             Exit For
        End If

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(internalCount, 2).Value = thisMachine Then
            Range(internalCount & ":" & internalCount).Cut
            Range(pasteRow & ":" & pasteRow).Insert
            pasteRow = pasteRow + 1
        End If
    Next internalCount
nextLoop:
Next rowCount
```

This works for one of the files, but another file in the same format is producing the error, and debugging highlights the line `Range(pasteRow & ":" & pasteRow).Insert` as the problem.

The data is first sorted by date/time (not shown) this also puts the shifts in order. It then loops through each row of the table, for each row it checks every row underneath it. If the row underneath contains the same day and shift and uses the same machine, the line is cut and pasted underneath the current row being read, or the previous row that was pasted (`pasteRow`). This tries to keep the machines in time order. If the date or shift do not match, the "internal" loop escapes and the program moves onto the next row.

Can anyone see why this would be causing a problem? Or why it would work for one set of data but not a second set?

Sorry if this is unclear, I've done my best to explain but it's hard to describe in text.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried this but no luck unfortunately, same error on the same line of code

Comment: what format is your data in? I have no issues sorting the above data in excel if the date / time column is in a date / time format. also what version are you in?

Comment: is it the shift that is causing the issue? you could use a helper column that convers Days to 1, etc?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2003 and the data is Custom (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm). Really the machine is the section that causes the issue I think, I use a standard sort on date/time, which works, and also groups the shifts but when I am trying to move the Machines so they are group together I get the problem. I will update the example above to include an extra shift

Comment: So it is ordered by **Day** ~> **Shift** ~> **Machine** ~> **Time**?

Comment: Yeah that is a lot simpler way to put it :)

Comment: that's good. can you separate the time into another column or are you constrained?

Comment: IYeah I should be able to easy enough I think, and then apply a four way sort somehow?

Comment: Just an aside - for me there is too much use of `Active` objects in this code and lots of objects are not fully qualified. I very rarely use Range without explicitly spelling out which sheet this range belongs to.

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/551662-excel-2003-visual-basic-applications-sort-4th-way.html#post2724006

Comment: Thanks glh that worked a treat. Anyway I can class this as answered since it was in a comment? o_O

Comment: No issues @Chrisrs I've added a comprehensive answer for you to close the loop if appropriate. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are needing to order your data by **Day** ~> **Shift** ~> **Machine** ~> **Time**?

If that is the case then you'll need a similar vba code to get around the Excel 2003 limitation, see [MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/551662-excel-2003-visual-basic-applications-sort-4th-way.html#post2724006) for more details:

> ```
> Range("A1:J1000").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
>     Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:= _
>     xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal  
> Range("A1:J1000").Sort Key1:=Range("F2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range _
>     ("G2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("A2"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
>     Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:= _
>     xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
>     DataOption3:=xlSortNormal
> ```